# Eclipse run config local file

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

Runtime exception trying to find properties file.  The properties file exists and is pointed to in a launch configuration:

```
-Dconfig.home="C:\development\eclipse workspace\config"
```

I have several other directories pointed to which do not cause a problem.  I get this stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c


    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.customizeContext(ContextLoader.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at 

... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Edit launch configuration VM arguments:

run->run configurations...->Tomcat 6.0(your server)->Arguments->VM Arguments

The local file reference should look like this:

```
-Dconfig.home="file:\\\development\eclipse workspace\config"
```

Yes, that is three slash in a row to escape the "escape slash"

Or, for OSX:

```
-Dconfig.home="file:///Users/gwn719/Documents/conf"
```